# awk command to print the text present in between two words of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, solaris

I have a variable as below

> a="My name is A. Her Name is B. His Name is C"

I need to print the text between "name" and "."

**Expected output is**

```
is A
is B
is C
```

**EDIT:** Solution should work both on Solaris and Linux Machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with GNU grep

```
$ grep -ioP '(?<=name ).+?(?=\.|$)' <<< "$a"
is A
is B
is C
```

This works with on solaris 5.8 with /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

```
$ echo "$a" | awk -F '[nN]ame |\\.' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}'
is A
is B
is C
```

Comment: in solaris it says `grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- P
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
`

Comment: it's a regex bracket expression that means: match either "n" or "N"

Comment: `man regexp` should get you started with the syntax of the regular expression language.

Comment: there is a text in between search pattern. it is `"YYYY-MM-DD;-1" :set` but it only prints `"YYYY-MM-DD;-1"`

Comment: well, you'd better show us your actual input text then.

Comment: This is the text `Her Name is B. His Name is C. My name is A on "YYYY-MM-DD;-1" :set .` Does the command has any length limitation while printing

Comment: I have raised a question similar to this. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165680/storing-command-output-lines-into-array-based-on-new-line-character

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
echo "$a"|awk -F '[nN]ame ' '{print $2}' RS='.'
is A
is B
is C
```

Comment: but I may have second string other than dot. This example is just for reference

Comment: @logan: you can use any other text in `RS` switch.

Comment: you meant `RS='2nd string'` ?

Comment: @anubhava : I have raised a question similar to this. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165680/storing-command-output-lines-into-array-based-on-new-line-character

Comment: sure let me take a look

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `bash` on Solaris, the following should work:

```
while read -r l; do
  echo "${l//*[Nn]ame /}";
done < <(tr '.' '\n' <<< "$a")
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
is A
is B
is C
```