# Storing command output lines into array based on new line character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a variable as below & i perform certain operations to print the output one by one as mentioned below.

```
a="My name is A. Her Name is B. His Name is C"
echo "$a" | awk -F '[nN]ame |\\.' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}'
```

**The output is**

```
is A
is B
is C
```

When I store the results into an array, it considers space as array separator and stores value. but i want to store the each line of the output to each array index values as below

```
x=($(awk -F '[nN]ame |\\.' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< "$a"))
```

**out puts ,**

```
${x[0]} = is
${x[1]} = A
..and so on...
```

**What i expect is**

```
${x[0]} = is A
${x[1]} = is B
${x[2]} = is C
```

Also `echo ${#x[@]} = 6` ; It should be `= 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OK try below:

i=0
while read v; do
    x[i]="$v"
    (( i++ ))
done < <(awk -F '[nN]ame |\\.' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< "$a")
```

Comment: But it returns full data `echo ${x[0]}` = `is A is B is C`

Comment: i expect `${x[0]} = is A
${x[1]} = is B
${x[2]} = is C`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the mapfile command (bash version 4 or higher):

```
tempX=$(awk -F '[nN]ame |\\.' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< "$a")
mapfile -t x <<< "$tempX"

~$ echo "${x[0]}"
is A
```

Comment: But it returns full data `echo ${x[0]}` = `is A is B is C`

Comment: Wrap argument of echo in quotes echo "${x[0]}"

Comment: now returns one by one... i want only the first line to in the first array.. (see my question) `$ echo "${x[0]}"
is A
is B
is C
[`

Comment: @logan For that you need bash version 4 or higher.